# How to rename each JPG file in a folder according to date/time stored in text file with same name?

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a batch file to rename each *.jpg file in a folder using the content of a *.txt file that has the same name.

The folder has about 100 JPEG files and 100 text files.
For example a text file named `001.txt` contains `O53F 012C 01/13/2018 01:47:07` and I want to rename the file `001.jpg` to `01/13/2018 01:47:07.jpg`.

Quite hard to explain, I hope it was clear enough.

I tried to look for some already existing questions about this task here on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find a proper question with this problem. The problem I have is combining the **FOR** loops.

I don't know where the problem really is. First I tried just to rename the *.txt files and not the *.jpg files (which seems easier), but ended up failing.

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do(
    for /f "tokens=7,8,9 delims= " %%i in (%%f) do(
        rename %%f %%i.txt
    )
)

pause
```

This one is an example which didn't work and I couldn't understand why.

What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` and `:` are not possible in a file name, see Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). I recommend to use the date/time format `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss` in file name.

The **FOR** syntax is incorrect because of a required space between `do` and `(`.

The task can be done with:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do for /F "usebackq tokens=3-8 delims=/: " %%A in ("%%I") do if not exist "%%C-%%A-%%B_%%D-%%E-%%F.jpg" ren "%%~nI.jpg" "%%C-%%A-%%B_%%D-%%E-%%F.jpg"
pause
```

Perhaps better to read is this code which is exactly the same as above:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=3-8 delims=/: " %%A in ("%%I") do (
        if not exist "%%C-%%A-%%B_%%D-%%E-%%F.jpg" (
            ren "%%~nI.jpg" "%%C-%%A-%%B_%%D-%%E-%%F.jpg"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

A command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` should be only used when really needed like more than one command to execute to improve efficiency on batch file processing.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`